# JQuery: Clicking <h1> in div also triggers click() in parent <div>

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I have a `<h1>` in a `<div>`. So when I click on the `<h1>` I also end up triggering the click function on the `<div>`. I am using `jquery` `click()` function.

Can someone please help how can I avoid calling the parent `click()` function.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: add event.stopPropagation(); inside h1 click handler or test the event.target element in the div click handler

Answer (score 1):

```
<body>
<div id="myDiv">
    <h1 id="myHeader">This is my Header</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#myDiv').click(() => {
        console.log('Div Clicked');
    })
    $('#myHeader').click((event) => {
        console.log('Header Clicked');
        event.stopPropagation();
    })
});
</script>
</body>
```

Now if h1 is clicked, stop event propagation prevents the click event to be propagated to parent div element.

In the console, you should only see Header clicked.